# Gradle's built in task JavaExec always runs the Java mainClass in fork (i.e. a new Jvm process)?

Tags: java, gradle, fork, javaexec-gradle-plugin

Is the Title correct ?

If i do JPS i can see the Java App as seperate process

And If I am correct then is there no config in JavaExec to run the Application inside the same Gradle Daemon process where gradle is running ?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task says:

> Executes a Java application in a child process.

There is no option that suggests anything else than a new process will be created.

It is all there in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @aled ... So its always in a new child process and not possible to run within same process like fork=false in Ant

Comment: Is there any way to set some Config like  `dontWaitForChildProcessOutput= true` for the JavaExec task. So that the Task gets completed without waiting for the Child process

Comment: Please read the documentation link I shared and post a new question if needed.